# Retrieving Data from Meteor Collections

Tags: meteor

I'm having a few problems when trying to get data from a Meteor Collection and I need some advice.

The collection has been defined, published, and subscribed successfully. If I send the data to a template, it displays fine:

```
Template.Lists.Projects = function(){
    return Projects.find();
};
```

But I am trying to use the data before displaying it, and this is where I run into problems. First, I'm getting some inconsistencies between find() and findOne(). find(selector) works fine and returns a cursor, but findOne(selector) returns "undefined." I really am only looking for 1 entry, so find() seems unnecessary.

Returns LocalCollection.Cursor:

```
var find = Projects.find({_id: "3fd33eed-9735-4376-860e-3be383beae2f"});
console.log(find);
```

Returns undefined:

```
var find = Projects.findOne({_id: "3fd33eed-9735-4376-860e-3be383beae2f"});
console.log(find);
```

My next problem arises when using .fetch() on the LocalCollection.Cursor. It returns an empty array.

```
var find = Projects.find({_id: "3fd33eed-9735-4376-860e-3be383beae2f"});
var fetch = find.fetch();
console.log(fetch);
```

all this returns is the following line:

[ ]

When I try to specify a specific key from the array I want to display, like:

```
var find = Projects.find({_id: "3fd33eed-9735-4376-860e-3be383beae2f"});
var fetch = find.fetch();
console.log(fetch.name);
```

It returns undefined.

I'm still familiarizing myself with Meteor and have never used MongoDB (or minimongo), so I'm probably just making some stupid mistake. If anyone can point it out to me I would be thrilled!

Comment: you're trying to use the data before displaying it, you can do this with template.templateName.rendered which if the rendered is inside a each, the template is represent data itself, like you can use "this", it's just your document. i'll put an example to prove.

Answer (score 4):

Your results for find() and findOne() are consistent. Basically, Mongo or minimongo is simply not finding a document that matches that _id. FindOne() is precisely like doing a find(selector, options).fetch()[0].

Your Lists.Projects template is likely expecting a collection, array or hash it can iterate over. You cannot return one specific document. If you are using {{#each Projects}} you must provide some way for the template to iterate not just a single value.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem,
The collection find() returned nothing when used from a `query.observe`.

The problem was the order of the `subscribe` of collections.

For example if you have a collection called `Lists` and one called `Projects`,

If you're getting the projects by observing a query on lists, and you had  :

```
Meteor.subscribe('Lists');
Meteor.subscribe('Projects');
```

What happens is the query observe trigger is called, but the Projects are not yet fetched from the server. So Projects.find().fetch().length = 0.

To fix it, simply do

```
Meteor.subscribe('Projects');    
Meteor.subscribe('Lists');
```

Answer (score 0):

if u've removed autopublish, what if u publish the collection to all user without using a publish name?

```
Meteor.publish null, ->
    Products.find {}
```

where u subscribe your collection ?

template helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelp = 'products', (id) ->
    Product.find _id: Session.get 'productId'
```

like if we have price in each product.
the template part looks like...

```
<template name="products-list">
    <div class="products-list">
        {{#each products}}
            {{> product-item}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="product-item">
    <div class="product-item">
        {{price}}
    </div>
</template>
```

the js part, i'll use coffeescript...

```
Template['product-item'].price = ->
    console.log @ # @ is this as it is product itself, if we have product inserted.
    console.log this
    return 'the price is: ' + @price
```

Comment: I already have autopublish off and have successfully published it by the server, subscribed to it by the client, and rendered it in a template. I'm really not sure what the code you put does (partially because I'm using JavaScript, not CoffeeScript), but I don't think it solves my problem. I just want to assign the keys of a specific entry to variables to be able to manipulate them before rendering it in a template.

Comment: can't really understand what u're trying to do, but you've said "But I am trying to use the data before displaying it", so i think you can manipulate value before template rendered.

Comment: If the OP uses javascript, I think it's better to write your answer in javascript as well, since as you can see, you risk posting an answer the OP can't actually understand! For that reason, I've downvoted this answer.

Comment: using coffee script in to help answer this is not really... well... helpful.  Its just going to further ovscure the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
Meteor.subscribe('testData', function() {
  var document = Documents.find();
  console.log(document); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working on the client and you never know when the client got all the data you need. Your functions can be fired when the collections are empty or still not finished synchronized. So you have to make a deferred request to your minimongo (when all data is available local)

And yes you can´t access stuff when its not rendered in the DOM via `getElementById()` or something but in your case you try to access data from the minimongo (your local mongodb version in the browser) not the DOM so your template is not important here.

Just wait until your subscribtion is ready that your minimongo own all the data with the `onReady` callback in your subscribtion call and fire your functions.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe

> **callbacks** (Function or Object).
>
> Optional. May include **onStop** and **onReady**
> callbacks. If there is an error, it is passed as an argument to
> onStop. If a function is passed instead of an object, it is
> interpreted as an onReady callback.