# retrieving data from mongodb collection in meteor using fetch()

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get data from a collection in meteor using this code

```
ShareUserLogs.find({"_id":shared_id}).fetch()[0]
```

shared_id is coming from route parameter, and it has no problem.

when I use `ShareUserLogs.find({"_id":shared_id})` returns `[object Object]`

```
ShareUserLogs.find({"_id":shared_id}).fetch()[0] works fine in console and in mongodb terminal but in code it returns `undefined`.
```

Also sometimes it works but most of the times returns `undefined`, I searched for this problem but couldn't find any solution. Looked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940807/retrieving-data-from-meteor-collections) but it didn't help and some other questions also.

Please help me in fixing this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are searching for a single document you might as well use the `findOne()` which does not return a Mongo cursor but a Mongo document.

Comment: I tried that still it is returning undefined

Comment: Check your input for things like "whitespace", either leading or trailing. It's a common enough mistake that things like that get passed through in parameters by badly formed hyperlinks etc. `console.log()` the parameter an look closely. If unsure, then apply `.trim()` to the parameter and see if queries are working properly then. If you are not matching expected results, then your input is basically not what you think it is.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I checked that as per you suggestion but still the same result.

Comment: I had to put my whole code inside Tracker.autorun(). Gog my answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225685/meteor-js-client-not-getting-data-from-mongo-db

Comment: Tracker.autorun() is not the complete solution because I cannot afford to have all my code inside this function.. but I have noticed that data is not inserting in the database quickly.

Comment: You need to wait for your subscription to be ready before querying it and/or handle errors when you're searching on an incompletely loaded collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're doing this in a meteor helper, you can do:

```
myHelper() {
  return ShareUserLogs.findOne({"_id":shared_id});
}
```

The problem you're likely running into is that when you subscribe to data, it is not available immediately. Therefore, your `find()` is coming back as a cursor with zero items, so accessing the 0th item in `fetch()` is going to error out.  If you're not using this in a helper, you'll probably want to use a reactive variable and an autorun to load in the data.